# Scrapy doesn't use params from settings.py

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, http-error

I am new to scrapy. My scrapy spider is blocked by ip by the site I want to parse. I get 520 error. If I initialize header/user_agent right in spider, and also set proxy in meta param of the scrapy.Request, I am able to send first request and get code 200, but then it stucks at 403 HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed. So I edited middlewares.py added CustomProxyMiddleware. In settings.py I set USER_AGENT and added DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES with CustomProxyMiddleware, but when I start spider, it doesn't use proxy and I suppose user_agent is also by default except mine.

middlewares.py

```
class CustomProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://103.35.64.12:3128"
        return None
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'SGinfotrackker'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['SGinfotrackker.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'SGinfotrackker.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True


DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 15

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'SGinfotrackker.middlewares.CustomProxyMiddleware': 350,
    'SGinfotrackker.middlewares.SginfotrackkerDownloaderMiddleware': None,
}
```

firstly I got

> Ignoring response <520 http://www.some_url.com>: HTTP status code is
>   not handled or not allowed

I then I recieve

> 403 HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `scrapy runspider` or `scrapy crawl` to run your spider? You should ideally use `scrapy crawl` in order to use your settings.

Also, as an alternative to your custom middleware, you can set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables to use a proxy in all requests.

You can set that externally before starting your spider, or inside your script at the beginning such as:

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://my/proxy'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://my/proxy'
```

Comment: I am using Scrapy 1.7.3 , and there is no command crawl, so I use runspider

Comment: Right - have you tried to set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables, without using the custom proxy?